# "TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable" even tough im not doing iteration

Tags: python, python-3.x

so i'm just learning state machine from ocw.mit.edu course 6.01SC, so itry write this code

```
class sm(object):
def start(self):
    self.state = self.startState
def step(self, input):
    (s,o) = self.getNextValues(self.state, input)
    self.state = s
    return o
def transduce(self, inputs):
    self.start()
    return [self.step(input) for input in inputs]

class delay(sm):
    def __init__(self,v0):
        self.startState = v0
    def getNextValues(self, state, input):
        return (input, state)

class cascade(sm):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.startState = 0
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.a.start()
        self.b.start()
    def getNextValues(self, state, input):
        return self.b.step(self.a.step(input))
a = delay(1)
b = delay(2)
c = cascade(a,b)
print(c.transduce([3,5,7,9]))
```

i try to cascade a and b, but i get "TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable" even tough i didn't create ant iteration. i've tried to debug and couldn't find it. please help. thanks!

Comment: `cascade.getNextValues` returns an int. `(s,o) = some_int` throws the error you're seeing. I can't tell you how to fix it because I don't have the slightest idea what your code is intended to do.

Comment: `sm` should not make calls to class methods that are not defined in itself or parent classes with an instance `self` as first argument. (such as the `getNextValues` call in `sm.step`)

Comment: Python gave you a complete stack trace including the line that had the error. Please post that in your question. We shouldn't have to dig through your code trying to figure out where the error is when python told you.